# Regex Replacement of part of string

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to replace a series of strings to extract the date. I'm using powershell and I have an example of part of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$Strings = @("this_is_a_test_8_20_2019_test", "this_is_a_test_8_19_2019_test")
$Strings -replace "[^0-9_]",""
```

Which leaves a result:

> ____8_20_2019_
>
> ____8_19_2019_

I'm trying to isolate just the _ characters that are not followed another _ and then digit. I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious but I'm not sure what. Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to match 1+ times not a digit `\D+` and assert using a positive lookahead `(?=` what is directly on the right is either an underscore or the end of the string `$`

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
\D+(?:_|$)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cD%2b%28%3f%3a_%7c%24%29&i=this_is_a_test_8_20_2019_test%0d%0athis_is_a_test_8_19_2019_test) | [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyW4pCgzL71YwVbBQUOpJCOzOB6IEuNLUotL4i3ijQyAyNASzFXSUcBUAJRDKNDkghunW5RakJOYnKqgFOOirWFvFV@joqmko6T0/z8A)

```
$Strings = @("this_is_a_test_8_20_2019_test", this_is_a_test_8_19_2019_test")
$Strings -replace "\D+(?:_|$)",""
```

Result

```
8_20_2019
8_19_2019
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I must have been screwing up the syntax I had for positive lookahead because I had basically given up on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you expect:

```
8_20_2019
8_19_2019
```

Then you need:

```
$Strings -replace "[^\d]+_|_[^\d]+",""
```

Answer (score 0):

presuming that you mean it when you say you want the date [instead of just the number string], this otta do the job. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- replaces the non-date string parts with nothing
- uses `::ParseExact()` to convert the date *string* into a datetime *object*
  for some reason, the date pattern will match two input digits to one pattern digit, but not one input digit to two pattern digits.

the code ...

```
$InStuff = @(
    "this_is_a_test_8_20_2019_test"
    "this_is_a_test_10_9_2001_test"
    'test_with_two_digits_12_12_2012_gobbledegook'
    'single_digit_test_1_2_1999_arglebargle'
    )

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $DateString = $IS_Item -replace '^.+_(\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}_\d{4})_.+$', '$1'
    [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, 'M_d_yyyy', $Null)
    }
```

output ...

```
2019 August 20, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
2001 October 09, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
2012 December 12, Wednesday 12:00:00 AM
1999 January 02, Saturday 12:00:00 AM
```